# Datalist inside Repeater ... Only getting header from repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, nested-datalist

I am new to using the Repeater as well as the Datalist.

I checked in the forum for the correct way to place a datalist inside a repeater.  Below is what I created, but it is only displaying the header of the repeater when I run it

```
<div id="divMarketSnapshot" style="vertical-align: central; width: 100%; height: 450px; overflow: auto" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrRanks" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed; width:100%;vertical-align:central">
        <tr style="height: 14pt; width:100%">
            <td class="xl6220798" colspan="33" style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;width:99.99%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 14pt; width:100%">
            <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
            <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
            <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
            <td class="xl1520798" colspan="27" style="text-align: left;font-size:14pt; font-weight: bold;width:81.1%"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Group") %></td>
            <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
            <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
            <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 14pt; width:100%">
            <td class="xl6220798" colspan="33" style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;width:99.99%"></td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="dlRanks" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr style="height: 14pt; width:100%" runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" colspan="16" class="xl6620798" style="width:48.48%">
                        <a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_ChartLink") %>"  " title="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_EventDirectionDesc") %>" target="_blank"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Name") %></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" style="width: 100%">
                    <td class="xl6720798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center">Date</td>
                    <td class="xl6720798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center">Market<br />Forecast</td>
                    <td class="xl6820798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center">RCG<br />Forecast</td>
                    <td class="xl6920798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center">Market<br />Actual</td>
                    <td class="xl7020798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center">RCG<br />Accuracy</td>
                    <td class="xl6920798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center">Equity Market<br />End Of Day</td>
                    <td class="xl7020798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_IndexHeader") %> Index<br />End Of Day</td>
                    <td class="xl7020798" colspan="2" style="width: 6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_CurrencyHeader") %><br />End Of Day</td>
                    <td class="xl1520798" style="width: 3.03%"></td>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="width:100%">
                    <td class="xl7120798" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_DateTime") %></td>
                    <td class="xl7120798" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Forecast") %></td>
                    <td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_ForecastDirection_Change") %>" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_ForecastDirection") %></td>
                    <td class="xl7120798" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Actuals") %></td>
                    <td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_ActualMarketResult_Font") %>" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_ActualMarketResult") %></td>
                    <td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Equity_EOD_Change") %>" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Equity_EOD_Price") %></td>
                    <td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Index_EOD_Change") %>" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Index_EOD_Price") %></td>
                    <td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Currency_EOD_Change") %>" colspan="2" style="width:6.06%; text-align: center"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_Currency_EOD_Price") %></td>
                    <td class="xl1520798" style="width:3.03%"></td>
                </tr>                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <tr style="width:100%">
                    <td style="width:3.03%"></td>
                    <td style="width:3.03%"></td>
                    <td class="xl1520798_15" colspan="4" style="width:12.12%; text-align: left">Next Forecast:  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_NextForecast") %></td>
                    <td style="width:3.03%"></td>
                    <td class="xl1520798_15" colspan="3" style="width:12.3%;text-align:center">Ultra Accuracy:  <span style="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_UltraAccuracy_Style") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventRow_UltraAccuracy") %></td>
                    <td colspan="7" style="width:21.21%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = "width:100%">
                    <td class="xl6820798" colspan="33" style="width:99.99%"></td>
                </tr>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code-behind on ItemDatabound:

```
Private Sub rptrRanks_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptrRanks.ItemDataBound 
    Dim dt As DataTable 
    Dim dlRanks As DataList = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("dlRanks"), DataList) 
    dt = TryCast(rptrRanks.DataSource, DataTable) 
    dlRanks.DataSource = dt 
    dlRanks.DataBind() 
End Sub
```

For the Datalist, I have 2 columns of data.
The structure that I am looking for is as follows:

```
Group
Event                                            Event
data col  data col   data col                    data col  data col   data col
data col  data col   data col                    data col  data col   data col
data col  data col   data col                    data col  data col   data col
data col  data col   data col                    data col  data col   data col

Footer information                               Footer information
```

Please let me know what I need to change so that it works properly.

Comment: It looks like there might be a problem where the data is not getting bound to the Datalist inside your repeater. Can you provide the code to how you are binding the data?

Comment: Sorry .. here is the code ... Private Sub rptrRanks_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptrRanks.ItemDataBound
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim dlRanks As DataList = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("dlRanks"), DataList)

        dt = TryCast(rptrRanks.DataSource, DataTable)
        dlRanks.DataSource = dt
        dlRanks.DataBind()
    End Sub

Comment: Does anyone see what my issue is?

Comment: I just ran a test and I did see that I am getting a null reference when adding the datatable as the datalist datasource (dlRanks.DataSource = dt )

Answer (score 0):

All, I found a link for doing Nested Repeaters.  I am working with my code to get this correct.  Here is the link  https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/57/displaying-one-to-many-relationships-with-nested-repeaters